# Highcharts - Stack a full serie (Bar chart)

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

So I have 2 series with data about events :

- a serie with views
- a serie with € values

1 item in each series relate to 1 event

I want a stacked bar chart with 2 column: 'Views', 'Value'

Each event will have it's own color.

Here is what I have so far :

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Views', 'Value']
    },
    yAxis: [{
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Value (€)'
        }
    },{
        min: 0,
        opposite: true,
        title: {
            text: 'Views'
        }
    }],
    legend: {
        reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Views',
        data: [{
            name: 'Event1',
            y: 500
        },{
            name: 'Event2',
            y: 200
        },{
            name: 'Event3',
            y: 350
        }],
        yAxis: 1
    }, {
        name: 'Value',
        data: [{
            name: 'Event1',
            y: 3000
        },{
            name: 'Event2',
            y: 2000
        },{
            name: 'Event3',
            y: 1500
        }]
    }]
});
```

I already setup 2 yAxis for value and views.

My problem is :

datas are stacked by events and not by categories. And as you will see, it's not even a good stacking because the first bar is hiding the second one.

Is it possible to do this with Highcharts ?

#### EDIT

[initial JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fxadv20h/1/)

Something more close to what I am looking for :

[New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxadv20h/3/)

But I can't find a way to properly setup my second yAxis

Comment: Why do you need second yAxis? When you have two series and each belongs to different axis then you can't stack bars. See working demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/fxadv20h/2/

Comment: But my need makes sense (in a reporting POV), I want an Y axis per category. That makes no sens to stack monetary values with pure count. Do you think there is a workaround ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display yAxis per category, then you need to split all data into separate points. You can connect series (in legend) using `linkedTo` option. That will require setting for each series color separately (to get matching colors), see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fxadv20h/4/

And code:

```
    series: [{
        id: 'e3',
        name: 'Event 3',
        data: [{
            name: 'Views',
            y: 500
        }],
        yAxis: 1
    },{
        id: 'e2',
        name: 'Event 2',
        data: [{
            name: 'Views',
            y: 200
        }],
        yAxis: 1
    },{
        id: 'e1',
        name: 'Event 1',
        data: [{
            name: 'Views',
            y: 150
        }],
        yAxis: 1
    }, {
        linkedTo: 'e3',
        name: 'Event 3',
        data: [{
            x: 1,
            name: 'Value',
            y: 1000
        }]
    },{
        linkedTo: 'e2',
        name: 'Event 2',
        data: [{
            x: 1,
            name: 'Value',
            y: 2000
        }]
    },{
        linkedTo: 'e1',
        name: 'Event 1',
        data: [{
            x: 1,
            name: 'Value',
            y: 1500
        }]
    }]
```